# Compiling Google Protobuf C++ in VS 2015 - test errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compile Google Protobuf (version 3.3.0) on my computer using Visual Studio 2015, but I am getting errors when checking my compiled libs.
I am using CMake and Visual Studio 2015. I used [this](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md) instructions for compiling the source code.

When I execute

```
nmake check
```

I get this results:

```
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1926 tests from 190 test cases ran. (17520 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1923 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 3 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] CommandLineInterfaceTest.DirectDependencies_NoViolation
[  FAILED  ] CommandLineInterfaceTest.ParseErrors
[  FAILED  ] CommandLineInterfaceTest.HelpText

 3 FAILED TESTS
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\protobuf-cpp-3.3.0\protobuf-3.3.0\cmake\build\release\tests.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Any hint? What am I doing wrong? I didn't change a single line of code. I just compiled the code that I got from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/protobuf-cpp-3.3.0.zip).

Comment: Try *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe*

Comment: I tried to recompile the code using the x86 native compiler, but I still get errors when I run "nmake check". I was reading protobuf issues at github and it looks like there are bugs in the "test.exe" program that is created when you compile protobuf on Windows, because other people are having similar issues. I think protobuf developers are not concerned about C++ Windows programmers. I will post this question on github too. Luckily, this issue will catch their eyes. Thanks for your help.